# Connections API - "Not enough permission"

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to perform GET request on

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/connections?q=viewer&projection=(paging)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-viewer /connections",
    "status": 403
}
```

The request had two permissions, r_1st_connections and r_compliance. But both the scopes cannot be used. They raise error while authenticating that they are unauthorized scopes. Are the docs are not updated? Also, I couldn't find these scopes in "Marketing Developer Platform endpoints" section of Linkedin Developer console.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this for getting the connections data:

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/connections/urn:li:person:{Person ID}`

You must have both 'r_1st_connections_size' and 'r_liteprofile' permissions from the user.

Here are the docs.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/connections-size

Hope could help